# Inline logo and company name in navbar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am beginner in ASP.NET MVC and in default project template I'm trying to add a logo in *navbar* with the company name, I have successfully added logo with company name. But, logo and company name both are not in the same line. I am trying to inline it. I spent lots of time but I could not find the solution. My output & code is given below.

**Output:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="/Home/Index" class="navbar-brand"> <img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" alt="Company logo" height="100"/> </a>
                @Html.ActionLink("Contact Lenses", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please tell me, how can I inline it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the height and margin-top of navbar.

I added a class name companyName to your Action link and added css `margin-top`.
Same `margin-top` value for `navbar-nav` class too.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Contact Lenses", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { 
            @class = "navbar-brand companyName"})
.companyName, .navbar-nav{
  margin-top: 15px !important;
 }
```

I changed the logo height to 50.

**Note**: I checked with some other logo image. I think that is bit larger than your logo size. That's why I changed height to 50, but you can keep it as your wish, then you need to set the margin-top value for `companyName` and `navbar-nav` accordingly. Then set `height = auto` to anchor tag, like bellow.

```
<a href="/Home/Index" class="navbar-brand myLogo"> 
  <img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" alt="Company logo" height="50"/> 
</a>
.myLogo{
  height:auto;
 }
```

I tested this code. Working as expected. 
Hope it helps :)